# using std namespace, why (or why not) should I prefix std::?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am
`using namespace std;`

Then, what's wrong with coding this?

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

As far as I know, I should put the "using namespace" or prefix the std:: each time interchangeably, but not both at the same time. What are the disadvantages of mixing both?

Also, how can I replace the code above? Is this acceptable?

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: It is up to you. Personally I think its preferable to explicit std:: before every function call to remember it is a standard library function, and to avoid possible conflicts if you define a function with the same name. But for small projects it really does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am `using namespace std;`

That's usually a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721), unless it's in a narrow scope to keep the pollution away from the rest of the program.

> Then, what's wrong with coding this?

Nothing; it's just more verbose than it needs to be. The name is available both as a qualified `std::cin` in any scope, and an unqualified `cin` in any scope where the name has been dumped by `using`. But I'd suggest not dumping the contents of the standard library into any other scope, to avoid the danger of library names conflicting with names I want to use.

> What are the disadvantages of mixing both?

You have both the name pollution that namespaces help avoid, and the less readable qualified names that `using` helps avoid; the disadvantages of both and the advantages of neither.

> Also, how can I replace the code above?

As you say, `cin.ignore(numeric_limits::max(), '\n');` will work if the contents of `std` have been dumped into an accessible scope. But I'd still recommend getting rid of the `using`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already going to the effort of prefixing your functions with `std::` then you really gain nothing by also having `using namespace std;` but you get the downsides that come with pulling everything from the standard library namespace in. Definitely don't do both. Also don't put `using namespace std` in your header files because the users of your code probably don't want that. Doing so is making a presumption that the users of your headers don't have any names that conflict with any of the standard library names, if this isn't the case then it's a pain for your users.

Generally speaking I usually always prefix with `std::` just to make sure that there's no name conflicts. However if there is a situation where you are just trying to reduce on typing then you can explicitly pull in just the name you want. For example:

```
 using std::cout;
 cout << "foo";
```

In this case you can reduce some typing without polluting the namespace by bringing in everything.